# C++ QT5 dynamic property

Tags: c++, qt5, qt5.5

I am using a widget with `Q_PROPERTY` entries. Now, I do have an internal map, and for each entry in that list has I'd like to add a dynamic property (name e.g. `"entry1Color"`).

I can add a dynamic property via `setProperty("entry1Color", Qt::green);` successfully, but I don't have a clue where the value (`Qt::green`) is being transferred to.
How to connect that set value to my map?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `setProperty`, this value is stored directly in your QObject, and you can use the [`property` getter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) to retrieve it. The value is returned as a [`QVariant`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), so you will have to cast it to the appropriate type. Example for a color:

```
// The boolean returned indicates if this is a newly created
// or existing  properly
bool was_just_create = myObject->setProperty("myColor", QColor(Qt::green));

// [...]
// And read it later on
QColor color1 = myObject->property("myColor").value<QColor>();
```

Properties declared explicitly with `Q_PROPERTY` are accessible in the exact same way, with the `property` getter. This is the same mechanism that is used by the QML engine to access your object properties, with `setProperty` and `property`.

Qt consistently use `setValue()` for setters, and `value()` (note the absence of *get*) for getters. Which is probably why you missed the getter in the first place :).

Answer (score 1):

When you are using QObject::setProperty on instance of QObject, it will be saved internally in QObject instance.

As I understand you want to implement it as QMap with value as member variable.
Here how it can be implemented:

**testclass.h**

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include <QColor>

class TestClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestClass(QObject *parent = 0);

    // mutators
    void setColor(const QString& aName, const QColor& aColor);
    QColor getColor(const QString &aName) const;

private:
    QMap<QString, QColor> mColors;
};

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

**testclass.cpp**

```
#include "testclass.h"

TestClass::TestClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void TestClass::setColor(const QString &aName, const QColor &aColor)
{
    mColors.insert(aName, aColor);
}

QColor TestClass::getColor(const QString &aName) const
{
    return mColors.value(aName);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include "testclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    TestClass testClass;
    testClass.setColor("entry1Color", Qt::green);

    qDebug() << testClass.getColor("entry1Color");


    return a.exec();
}
```

But also, it can be useful to check for how QMap works and which limitations for  pairs it has.

Answer (score 0):

> When you are using QObject::setProperty on instance of QObject, it will be saved internally in QObject instance.

@Dmitriy: Thanks for clarification and the example code.
Now I do can read the value set by setProperty, fine so far.

But this is not all I want. I'd like to have some kind of a set function that will be called by the dynamic property setter, like the WRITE fn declaration for static Q_PROPERTY entries.

In my case, I create a `dynamic property` by calling setProperty("entry1Color") just in time with `mColors.insert` call.
The value should be written directly in my map["entry1Color"]. I did not yet stumble upon any idea to achieve this.